# Webpack 5 production mode result in a broken app

Tags: webpack, production

I have 2 modes:

1. Development mode -> code works!
2. Production mode -> code's broken.

**The common code**

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "./src/template.html"
  })],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/i,
        use: [
          "style-loader", // Inject styles into DOM
          "css-loader", // Turns css into commonJS
          "sass-loader" // Turns sass into css
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**The production code**

```
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "main.[contenthash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
});
```

The console log error:

```
knockout-min.js:79 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return displayMessage }"
Message: Unable to process binding "event: function(){return { mouseenter:$parent.enableMarker,mouseleave:$parent.disableMarker,click:$parent.hoverClick} }"
Message: $parent is not defined
    at event (eval at parseBindingsString (knockout-min.js:74), <anonymous>:3:78)
    at e (knockout-min.js:75)
    at knockout-min.js:77
    at init (knockout-min.js:99)
    at knockout-min.js:79
    at Object.K (knockout-min.js:41)
    at knockout-min.js:79
    at Object.C (knockout-min.js:11)
    at q (knockout-min.js:78)
    at l (knockout-min.js:76)
```

All of the libraries are loaded externally from cdns.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work by adding **minify: false,** to **HtmlWebpackPlugin**.
A solution with keeping production in minify will be great.

```
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "./src/template.html",
    minify: false,
  })],
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for this. I had a similar issue, broken production build with no errors, but the code did not enter the main entry-point. Stumped for hours. Turns out it was this option.

Comment: Had to disable minimize also for HTML loaded with html-loader (https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/#minimize), because Knockout comments were stripped out.